# Cannot run program "Rscript" in eclipse, but can run it through terminal

Tags: eclipse, r, maven

Mac OSX 10.7.5, can run Rscript in terminal:

```
Mac-mini lenskit-demo$ rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
```

But can`t run it through eclipse:

```
[INFO] 22:28:16.672 o.g.l.eval.EvalTarget: beginning execution of analyze
[INFO] 22:28:16.672 o.g.l.eval.EvalProject: running task exec
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:26.859s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 16 22:28:17 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grouplens.lenskit:lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:2.0-M1:run-eval (default-run-eval) on project lenskit-demo: Execution default-run-eval of goal org.grouplens.lenskit:lenskit-eval-maven-plugin:2.0-M1:run-eval failed: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Please, someone can tell me How to solve this?

Comment: I am not a Mac guru, however this could be a path problem.  Does it work if you put the full path to rscript in the maven configuration?  Also, I note that the error message says "Rscript" can't be found, while when you run the command in a terminal it's "rscript".  Is OSX case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

There is a cross-platform bolt-on package for eclipse to use with R:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/statet/